# Upgraded Spring, Now Freemarker throws NoSutchMethod error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, runtime-error, freemarker

I had a perfectly working Spring applicaton  (4.2.7 -> 4.3.7)   Simple upgrade,  but now when I deploy catalina.out is giving me a:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: freemarker.template.Configuration.<init>(Lfreemarker/template/Version;)V
    at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.newConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:320)
```

I looked through the API but doesn't look like anything changed.  I also can confirm the freemarker-2.3.20.jar   is in the lib directory,   but this looks like a spring issue

Answer (score 0):

Took a bit of searching,  but Spring also upgraded Freemarker to 2.3.23 --  So use that in your pom and it should work.

Comment: The current and recommended one is 2.3.25-incubating (where "-incubating" is required by the ASF for branding reasons). I don't know why Spring 4.3.5 (I guess that's what you meant) comes with a 1.5 year old FreeMarker version instead, but I guess they are too confused by "-incubating".